# Rewrite page url as subdomain in apache htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a lot of page URLs like domain.com/page I want a rewrite rule that will change all my pages URLs as page.domain.com meaning whatever will come after the domain just rewrite it as a subdomain

example urls

expertpro.cloud/hot-to-write-blog      to         hot-to-write-blog.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/game                   to           game.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/nibm-full-form          to        nibm-full-form.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/choclate              to          choclate.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/harmony-in-life           to        harmony-in-life.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/paki-cold-places       to          paki-cold-places.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/you-are-one          to           you-are-one.expertpro.cloud

I already have some code for Nginx

```
             The empty location = / block is necessary so that you don't redirect 
               http://example.com/ to http://.example.com/.


             //replacing domain name in rewrite rule

           location = / {
           # don't redirect $server_name/
             }


          location / {
            rewrite ^\/([^\/]*).*$ https://$1.$server_name/ redirect;
```

Comment: Your question is vague. Please invest some more effort into precision. Give some examples for specific URLs and how they should get rewritten. Is this about one folder / "subdomain" or multiple? And the "base domain" should not get used any more at all? There is an "edit" link below your question. _Use it ..._

Comment: @arkascha    expertpro.cloud/hot-to-write-blog      to         hot-to-write-blog.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/game                   to           game.expertpro.cloud
 
expertpro.cloud/nibm-full-form          to        nibm-full-form.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/choclate              to          choclate.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/harmony-in-life           to        harmony-in-life.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/paki-cold-places       to          paki-cold-places.expertpro.cloud

expertpro.cloud/you-are-one          to           you-are-one.expertpro.cloud

Answer (score 0):

OK, all you need is an internal rewrite, as it looks:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

You obviously need the rewriting module to be loaded into your http server.

That would be a variant which additionally redirects direct requests to the internal URL:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)(/.*)?$ https://$1.example.com$2 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

Here it makes sense to start out with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only to change that into a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as expected.

In general you should try to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. If you have no access to that you can instead use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but those come with disadvantages. You need to enable the interpretation of such files in that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Replacing this [R=301] with [R=301,QSA,L] worked for me.        
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?hostingwebsite\.io$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)(/.*)?$ https://$1.hostingwebsite.io$2 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main-sitemap*

Comment: OK, the `QSA` flag makes sense if required, your question stated no such thing. The `L` flag does not make sense, an external redirection _always_ terminates the current rewriting process.